# Linked Databases in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL Developer to host some data, but I think my configuration isn't right. Lets say I have a database named DB1 with the tables

```
DB1
-db1_name
-db1_cities
```

The problem is when I try to create a new database let say DB2, SQLdeveloper creates the database but it also includes all the tables from DB1 (db1_name,db1_cities). Also if I removed the tables from DB2, the tables also  disappear from DB1. How can I change my configuration so this does not happen anymore and each database is independent from each other?

To create a new data base I usually go in the SQL Developer GUI interface  to connections, then I click on new Connection and provide the connection name, user name, and password. I leave the connection type to basic and the role to default. The host name as local host, and the default port.

Comment: How do you create the db? can you provide us with your steps or your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because you are currently adding a new database *connection* instead of creating a database.

To create a new database from scratch, take a look at [this link](http://www.fehily.com/books/createdb/createdb_oracle_11g_2.html), it'll take you through step by step on creating the new database.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but would i get through the GUI file tab or how do I get to the assistant window?

Comment: @ Daniel It will be located wherever `Oracle` is installed. If on Windows:  `Start > All Programs > Oracle - OraDb11g_home1 > Configuration and Migration Tools > Database Configuration Assistant` Where it usually is. If its in a different place, try searching for it on your PC. DBCA or database configuration assistant  If on UNIX/LINUX, open the terminal and type in dbca

Comment: I just realized i have the express edition. Express edition only allows for one database, therefore I don't have access to the  DBCA. In order to get DBCA I need to download sql developer standard edition. thanks for the help